# Accessing Google Analytics Custom Reports with the Python Client

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have created a Google Analytics Custom report for my website that I want to access using python. Can anyone point me too a simple example?

Ive scoured the pages of code.google.com for hours now and Im still completely baffled.

Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

You can try google python client http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/.
Here is analytics docs http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/ and more specifically look at http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/dimsmets/customvars.html

OR

You can use Google API explorer, here is what I am using [https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=analytics&_v=v3&_m=report.get&end-date=2011-11-18&start-date=2011-10-17&metrics=ga:visits&ids=ga:52179970](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=analytics&_v=v3&_m=report.get&end-date=2011-11-18&start-date=2011-10-17&metrics=ga%3avisits&ids=ga:52179970). Replace ids(ga:52179970) with your ids (look at URL of custom report) and replace metrics with your desired matrics in csv format.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this cannot be done through the API with Python or any other language.

There is a feature request in for it:

[Issue 23: Expose Custom Reporting trough API](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=23&q=custom%20report&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)